# Greeting depending on the time of day

Tags: twig

I would like to create a greeting depending on the time of day, in Twig.

Something like (purely as an example):

```
{% if hours < 12 %} {{translate('Morning')}} {% elseif hours < 18 %} {{translate('Evening')}} {% else %} {{translate('Night')}} {% endif %}
```

As that's all I have, I am reaching out here to check if anyone could help me out.

This is how it would look in javascript, but I'd like to use Twig:

```
var thehours = new Date().getHours();
    var themessage;
    var morning = ('Good morning');
    var afternoon = ('Good afternoon');
    var evening = ('Good evening');

    if (thehours >= 0 && thehours < 12) {
        themessage = morning; 

    } else if (thehours >= 12 && thehours < 17) {
        themessage = afternoon;

    } else if (thehours >= 17 && thehours < 24) {
        themessage = evening;
    }

    $('.greeting').append(themessage);
```

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the difficulty you are facing? Your example logic seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Translator component (`composer require symfony/translation`).
 You could use `transchoice` as defined [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#twig-templates)

```
{% currentHour = 'now'|date('H') %}

{% transchoice currentHour %}
    [0,12[ Good morning |]12,17[ Good afternoon  |]17,24[ Good evening
{% endtranschoice %}
```

This solution allows you to handle languages where we don't say good morning, for example in french:

```
{% transchoice currentHour %}
    [0,17[ Bonjour  |]17,24[ Bonsoir
{% endtranschoice %}
```

Comment: I'll go ahead and test this. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like transchoice is build into symfony, and not build into twig.

Comment: @Mykita what is the library behind your fuction `translate` ?